# kafka nginx 400 157 "-" "-"

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka

I wana create docker-compose file nginx proxy for kafka
but nginx had problem 400

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrBxH.png)
how to modify my code

192.168.0.8 is broker server
1922.168.0.16 is producer server and nginx server

1. docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.5-alpine
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    container_name: nginx-server
```

2. nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
events {
 worker_connections 1000;
}

http {

 upstream all {
  
    ip_hash;
  server 192.168.0.8:9092;
  server 192.168.0.8:9093;
  server 192.168.0.8:9094;
}
 server {
  
  server_name  192.168.0.8;

  listen 4000;
  
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://all/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
 }
 
}
```

upstream all is 3 broker server

3. kafkajs config

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');
const { Partitioners } = require('kafkajs');

const kafkaClient = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'icas-client',
  brokers: ['192.168.0.8:4000'],
});

const producer = kafkaClient.producer({ createPartitioner: Partitioners.LegacyPartitioner });

const consumer = kafkaClient.consumer({ groupId: 'icas' });
module.exports.kafkaClient = kafkaClient;
module.exports.producer = producer;
module.exports.consumer = consumer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka uses TCP, not HTTP, so this will not work

Kafka clients already load balance, natively, so there's no reason to introduce a reverse proxy